# gwt:launching pdf in new window on click of help menu

Tags: gwt

in gwt wen i click on help menu...i need to open a new window showing the help pdf kept inside my client code

Comment: that pdf is not from server...it resides in the same client package

Answer (score 1):

You question is not very clear: how do you open the PDF? If you have a link then you can add the attribute `target="_blank"` in the corresponding anchor. Something like this:

```
<a href="your_file.pdf" target="_blank">Help PDF</a>
```

If you want to do it from your java code, you can do this:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(url_to_your_pdf, "_blank", "");
```

Note however that you don't have full control whether this opens a new window or tab: see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907531/gwt-open-page-in-a-new-tab).

Comment: i have help menu item...help data is in pdf...i added that pdf file to war folder...on clicking help menu item i need to open that help pdf in anew window...can u give me a syntax for this

Comment: That depends on how your menu is implemented. You may have to implement a ClickHandler. You could perhaps post the relevant section of your code: this would help people looking at your question at figuring out a possible solution.

Comment: MenuItem userGuide = new MenuItem();
  userGuide.setText(constants.userGuide());
  userGuide.setId("3");
  userGuide.setEnabled(true);
  userGuide.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<MenuEvent>() {

   @Override
   public void componentSelected(final MenuEvent ce) {
     
 //i need to add code to launch a new window containg pdf       
   }
  });

Comment: I edited my answer adding a suggestion